# Why does Roslyn not throw an error for method unification?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

If you attempt to implement two interfaces that can possibly "unify" for a certain set of type parameters Roslyn will throw an error:

```
public interface IFoo<T1, T2>
{
    void Method(T1 a, T2 b);
}

public class Foo<T1, T2> : IFoo<T1, T2>, IFoo<T2, T1>
{
    public void Method(T2 a, T1 b) { }
    public void Method(T1 a, T2 b) { }
}
```

The Foo class will not compile and Roslyn will give you an error saying "`Foo<T1, T2>` cannot implement both `IFoo<T1, T2>` and `IFoo<T2, T1>` because they may unify for some type parameter substitutions." Even though it is fine for most type substitutions, Roslyn will not let you even declare this class because of the possibility that someone uses a type substitution where T1 == T2.

However, the compiler has no problem with letting you declare this:

```
public class Bar<T1, T2>
{
    public void Method(T1 t) { }
    public void Method(T2 t) { }
}
```

This class compiles fine and an error is only thrown once the client attempts to call the method:

```
var bar = new Bar<int, int>();
bar.Method(5);
```

Here Roslyn gives an error saying "This call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `Bar<T1, T2>.Method(T1)` and `Bar<T1, T2>.Method(T2)`."

I was wondering why in these two very similar situations the compiler acts so differently. Should the compiler throw an error as soon as you declare two methods that could possibly unify?

Comment: The problem there is that the _interface mapping_ becomes ambiguous..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each individual `Bar.Method` method can be called:

```
public class Bar<T1, T2> {
    public void Method(T1 t) {
        Console.WriteLine("FirstMethod");
    }
    public void Method(T2 t) {
        Console.WriteLine("SecondMethod");
    }
}
public static void CallFirstMethod<T1, T2>(Bar<T1, T2> bar, T1 t) {
    bar.Method(t);
}
public static void CallSecondMethod<T1, T2>(Bar<T1, T2> bar, T2 t) {
    bar.Method(t);
}
public static void Test() {
    var bar = new Bar<int, int>();
    CallFirstMethod(bar, 5);
    CallSecondMethod(bar, 6);
}
```

Thus, there is no reason to produce error in this case.